# How can I recover files from my home folder?

Tags: permissions, mount, mac

I have a hard drive from a dead laptop, and I need to get some files out of my `/home` directory. The laptop was running Ubuntu 16.04, and I have successfully mounted the drive on Mac OS, and am able to access some of the files. However, my home directory is inaccessible. I get `Permission denied` when I try to access it.

How can I access the files in my home directory? I know the password for the user that owned the directory on Ubuntu, but my current user is the user on my Mac, not the user on Ubuntu.

I have tried `chown` but that gives me `Function not implemented`. What can I do?

Comment: 1. Have you tried to boot a PC (not a Mac) computer from this HDD? An Installed Ubuntu system is often (but not always) portable between PC computers; 2. Was the home directory encrypted?

Comment: I don't own a PC computer. The home directory was not encrypted.

Comment: When the home directory is not encrypted, you should be able to boot an Ubuntu live drive (DVD or USB), and the live Ubuntu system should be able to read all Ubuntu's file systems on the old HDD. You may need elevated permissions (that you get with `sudo` for command line tools and with `sudo -H` with graphical (GUI) tools).